# Save view changes after animation ends

Tags: java, android

In my app, i have a full screen FrameLayout view,
I am fired scale (Resize) animation, after that i need to make some actions in the updated size.

the view of the new size is saved in the UI, but when i check the updated size (Height + Width)  it retrieve the original size (before the animation started)

**So, how can I save the changes that created by the animation?**

( `animation.setFillAfter(true);` not available in this case)

```
 mView.animate()
.setStartDelay(3000)
.scaleX(0.3f).scaleY(0.3f)
                   .y((screenHeight * 0.3f +110)).x((-screenWidth * 0.3f - 70))
                   .alpha(0.7F)
                   .setDuration(300)
                   .withEndAction(() -> {
                   });
```

Comment: what type of changes you want to save means before animation or after animation ?

Comment: i need to save the scale and the positions (.y & .x) only **after** animation